# SpaCy: Add tokenizer special case for addresses (locations) consisting of more than one word

Tags: python, spacy

I want to extract locations out of different sentences provided by users with the help of SpaCy (for example that when the user inputs "New York New Orleans" I get the two Locations "New York" and "New Orleans" out of it). Since SpaCy offers the very handy possibility to add special cases to its tokenizer, I tried to them for different locations (as described in the docs [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/customizing-tokenizer)). As long as the locations consist of only one word, everything works fine. But as soon as the locations consist of two or more words (as the aforementioned examples of "New York", "New Orleans" and many more) the special cases are not handled correctly anymore.
I guess this is due to the fact that the special cases are only handled *after* the text is split into tokens (the text is split on every blank space, as is described [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/customizing-tokenizer#how-tokenizer-works)). This would mean that SpaCy splits the text, say "New York New Orleans" into the tokens "New" "York" "New" "Orleans" and is later on not able to match a special case on any of the tokens.

So, my question is as follows: Is there a way that I can add special cases consisting of two words, such that SpaCy tokenizes them correctly? To stay with the example, that "New York New Orleans" is recognized as the two locations "New York" and "New Orleans" - given that I did add a special case for each of them.
Or is there another best practice (that I might have missed) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I used Entity Recognition from `spacy`? You can filter label equal to `GPE` later on when you do entities recognition.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp("New York New Orleans")

for ent in doc.ents:
    print((ent.label_, ent.text))
```

The output is

```
('GPE', 'New York')
('GPE', 'New Orleans')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have mentioned that I'm working with the German Language Model. Sorry, that was my fault. I used the example because if the german model is used, SpaCy is not able to recognize the two locations in "New York New Orleans" (whereas it recognizes the locations correctly as you pointed out with the english model).
I guess SpaCy is only able to recognize major locations. When I try the english model with the example of "Carson City Santa Rosa" it detects "ORG" "Carson City Santa Rosa".

Comment: Yeah, in this case spacy only recognize the location when you have text with comma: doc = nlp("Carson City, Santa Rosa"). This one will give GPE for each words